# Status Bar is transparent with UIHostingController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uihostingcontroller

The following is a simplified project to highlight the problem, which I have in a real project.

I have a project, where I add a SwiftUI view with UIHostingController, and the status bar at the top is transparent. I see it when I scroll the SwiftUI view.

It is easy to recreate, create a new iOS project with storyboard, and embed the `ViewController` in the storyboard with a NavigationView.

Then replace the `ViewController` content with this:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: ScrollView { MySwiftUIView() })
        self.addChild(hostingController)
        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingController.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingController.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        
        self.title = "MyTitle"
    }
}

struct MySwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text("This is line \(index)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The status bar is transparent, and shows the white background of the view:

[image: Before scrolling]

And when I start scrolling the `MySwiftUIView`, it is even more apparent that the status bar is transparent:

[image: After scrolling]

I have searched around to find a solution to this, because I want the status bar to have the same color as the navigation bar, and not showing content from the SwiftUI view in the status bar. But so far I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

to

```
hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

I'm not 100% sure, it's your expected result, but it does remove the `SwiftUI` content overlap.

Comment: Glad it helped, note also that you can add `view.backgroundColor = .yellow` in `viewDidLoad`, it will color status bar also.

Answer (score 1):

This is also a trick:

```
 func setStatusBar() {
        if #available(iOS 13, *)
        {
            let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
                    .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
                    .compactMap({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
                    .first?.windows
                    .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
            let statusBar = UIView(frame: (keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame) ?? CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: statubarHeight))
            statusBar.backgroundColor = .green
            keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)
        } else {
            let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
            if statusBar.responds(to:#selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
                statusBar.backgroundColor = .green
            }
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was super cool trick, I am using it together with the other answer in my real project